# Create infinite parallel pattern

Tags: html, css, d3.js, canvas, svg

I would like to create infinite repeating line pattern. However, lines have offset in both horizontal and vertical direction from the end of the line with some defined spacing. Shown below is the illustration:

[Elemental Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSi9I.png)

Now I would like this pattern offset in both horizontal and vertical direction. Usage of pattern should look like Fig 2.

Right now, I'm manually doing trigonometry to create lines given width, and height of rectangle but I would like to utilize `<pattern>` in SVG. Without `<pattern>` It is very hard for me to change scale of the rendered pattern.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find way to do offset repetition from any of the tutorials online or reference docs.

What I have tried:

This is what I have done so far given S, length of line, X offset, Y offset

1. Create Box of Width, Height with bottom left as (0,0)
2. Create first line from 0,0 to L,0
3. Create another line from L+S,0 to 2L+S, 0
4. Once (x,y) hit the boundary of the box - stop

Now repeat (1,4) by propagating offset in top direction. If after offset, you are outside of the box :- Draw a very big Line, if it intersects with box: start drawing from the intersection point.

Repeat until 2 set of offset do not intersect with the box. I wrote all of this in python and created `<line>`.

Unfortunately I cannot scale this, and I cannot have rectangle that is filled by pattern change in size. I'm rendering 100s of line for simple pattern.

Here is my python code:

```python
def cosd(angle):
    return np.cos(angle*np.pi/180.0)

def sind(angle):
    return np.sin(angle*np.pi/180.0)


class pattern():
    def __init__(self, angle, x, y, x_offset, y_offset, dashes):
        self.angle = angle
        self.p = Point(x, y)
        self.x_offset = x_offset
        self.y_offset = y_offset
        self.dashes = dashes
        self.svg_lines = []

    # Check if the origins are in the box
    def in_box(self, poly):
        if poly.encloses_point(self.p) == False:
            if len(intersection(self.p, poly)) < 1:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return True

    def offset_me(self, direction='+'):
        """
            x offset creates vector U in direction of angle of Length = x_offset
            y offset creates vector V in direction perp of U with length of y_offset
            Adding these two vector provides new offset location 
        """
        x1 = self.p[0]
        y1 = self.p[1]
        angle = self.angle
        theta = 90 - angle 
        if direction == '-':
            theta = -1*theta
        x3 = x1 + cosd(angle)*self.x_offset + cosd(theta)*self.y_offset
        y3 = y1 + sind(angle)*self.x_offset + sind(theta)*self.y_offset
        self.p = Point(x3, y3)
        print "Offsetting in " + direction

    def draw_svg_line(self, p1, p2):
        print Segment(p1, p2)
        self.svg_lines.append(Segment(p1, p2))

    def clean_report_svg_lines(self,poly):
        rep = self.svg_lines
        result = []
        for item in rep:
            if len(intersection(item,poly)) > 0 or poly.encloses_point(item.points[0]):
                if item not in result:
                    result.append(item)

        txt = []
        for item in result:
            x1 = item.points[0][0]
            y1 = item.points[0][1]
            x2 = item.points[1][0]
            y2 = item.points[1][1]
            svg_str = '<line x1="{}" y1="{}" x2="{}" y2="{}" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:0.5" />'.format(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            txt.append(svg_str)

        return txt

    def draw_all(self, poly):

        # Draw in Positive Direction
        starter_point = self.p.copy()
        #self.draw_me(poly, direction='+')
        while poly.encloses_point(self.p):
            self.draw_me(poly, direction='+')

        self.p = starter_point
        starter_point = self.p.copy()
        #self.draw_me(poly, direction='-')
        while poly.encloses_point(self.p):
            self.draw_me(poly, direction='-')

    def draw_me(self, poly, direction='+'):
        angle = self.angle
        # Draw backwards
        my_dash = self.dashes
        if direction == '-':
            my_dash.reverse()

        for L in self.dashes:
            abs_L = abs(L)
            if L > 0:
                if direction == '-':
                    x2 = self.p[0] - cosd(angle)*abs_L
                    y2 = self.p[1] - sind(angle)*abs_L
                else:
                    x2 = self.p[0] + cosd(angle)*abs_L
                    y2 = self.p[1] + sind(angle)*abs_L
                line = Segment(self.p, Point(x2,y2))
                inter = intersection(line, poly)
                self.draw_svg_line(self.p,Point(x2,y2))
                self.p = Point(x2,y2)
            elif L == 0:
                pass
            elif L < 0:
                if direction == '-':
                    self.p = Point(self.p[0] - abs_L*cosd(angle), self.p[1] - abs_L*sind(angle))
                else:
                    self.p = Point(self.p[0] + abs_L*cosd(angle), self.p[1] + abs_L*sind(angle))      

    def print_me(self):
        print self.p
        print self.angle

    def travel(self,p,L, direction='+'):
        angle = self.angle
        x2 = p[0] + cosd(angle)*L
        y2 = p[1] + sind(angle)*L
        if direction == '-':
            x2 = p[0] - cosd(angle)*L
            y2 = p[1] - sind(angle)*L
        p2 = Point(x2,y2)
        return p2

    def get_starting_point(self, poly):
        # Its already in box
        if self.in_box(poly):
            return True, self.p

        length = sum([abs(x) for x in self.dashes])
        p2 = self.travel(self.p, length)
        if poly.encloses_point(p2):
            return True, p2

        if intersection(Line(self.p, p2),poly):
            # It has intersections but which way?
            i = intersection(Line(self.p, p2),poly)
            print type(i[0])
            if isinstance(i[0], sympy.geometry.point.Point2D):
                i = Segment(i[0], i[1])
            else:
                i = i[0]
            p_midpoint = i.midpoint
            print p_midpoint[0]
            direction = '+'
            if p_midpoint[0] - self.p[0] <= 0:
                direction = '-'
            # Now we know which way it is go back until we hit....
            while len(intersection(Segment(self.p, p2),poly)) < 1:
                self.p = self.travel(self.p, length,direction)
                p2 = self.travel(self.p, length,direction)
            return True, p2
        else:
            return False, None


    # Get origins to the box 
    def offset_draw(self, poly):
        starting_p = self.p.copy()
        possible, self.p = self.get_starting_point(poly)
        self.draw_all(poly)

        # Positive Draw
        while possible:
            self.draw_all(poly)
            self.offset_me(direction='+')
            possible, self.p = self.get_starting_point(poly)

        self.p = starting_p
        print self.p
        self.offset_me(direction='-')
        possible, self.p = self.get_starting_point(poly)

        # Negetive Draw
        while possible:
            self.draw_all(poly)
            self.offset_me(direction='-')
            possible, self.p = self.get_starting_point(poly)
```

I copy paste result of my python code (line elements) into svg pattern tag: 
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MraGJQ?page=1&)

Comment: I guess I will edit what I have tried so far...

Comment: That would be great and the proper way to get quality answers on this website.

Comment: I wrote my attempt

Comment: Anyone who doesn't know anything about coding will write that, @pozza. We only help programmers here. Otherwise, [so] would turn into a *"give me teh codez, pleaz"* website, which is something we want to avoid.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu there! What else can I do?

Comment: I'll format that a bit better for you and we'll wait. I'm not good in python and was hoping you would post what you tried in frontend (CSS + JS - maybe). I could have helped with that. But hopefully someone able to help will get to this.

Comment: Right now I'm rendering individual line element like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MraGJQ?page=1&. I copy paste my results from python code :( I don't know how to do this in svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this `d3`, I assume a d3 answer is acceptable?  Regardless, it'll show you how to build the pattern and should be easily translatable to `python`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var width = 1000,
          height = 1000,
          offsetX = 25,
          offsetY = 25,
          lineLength = 75,
          strokeWidth = 3;
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);
        
      var p = svg.append('pattern')
        .attr('id', 'myPattern')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', (offsetX + lineLength) / width)
        .attr('height', (offsetY * 2) / height);
      
      p.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", lineLength)
        .attr("y1", strokeWidth)
        .attr("y2", strokeWidth)
        .style("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
        .style("stroke", "black");
        
      p.append("line")
        .attr("x1", offsetX)
        .attr("x2", lineLength + offsetX)
        .attr("y1", offsetY + strokeWidth)
        .attr("y2", offsetY + strokeWidth)
        .style("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
        .style("stroke", "black");
        
      p.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", lineLength)
        .attr("cy", strokeWidth)
        .attr("r", strokeWidth);
        
      p.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", strokeWidth)
        .attr("cy", strokeWidth)
        .attr("r", strokeWidth);
        
      p.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", offsetX)
        .attr("cy", offsetY + strokeWidth)
        .attr("r", strokeWidth);
        
      p.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", lineLength + offsetX - strokeWidth)
        .attr("cy", offsetY + strokeWidth)
        .attr("r", strokeWidth);
        
      svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("fill","url(#myPattern)");

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```